# Low Rank and Low Dimension approximation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, svd

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where $m<n$. Also $rank(A)=m$ and $svd(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{USV^{T}}$, where $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mathbf{S}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

I know that $rank$-$k$ approximation of $\mathbf{A}$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \mathbf{u_i}s_{ii}\mathbf{v_i^T}
\end{equation}

Notice that $\mathbf{A}_k \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ i-e dimensions remains unchanged.

However for my problem I need a new approximation $\mathbf{A}_{k}^{'}$ that is both

1. *low-rank*
2. *low-dimension*

By low-dimension I mean $\mathbf{A}_{k}^{'}\in\mathbb{R}^{m^{'}\times n^{'}}$ such that $m^{'}<m$ and $n^{'}<n$.

Since this is not a standard thing, I am looking for right

1. Mathematical expression
2. Paraphrase it in English language.

I would appreciate any help here from the experts.

**Example:**
[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, but you'll have to give us **some** notion of what you're looking for, perhaps an example would help. For instance, take the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{3\\&2\\&&1}
$$
what matrix $A'$ do you think is a good "low-dimension approximation" for $A$?  Why do you consider your matrix to be a good approximation?

Comment: Let $\mathbf{A^'} \ in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. I will do a sliding window like operation using $\mathbf{A^'}$ over $\mathbf{A}$ and compute euclidean distance. In that way $ \mathbf{A^'} $ would be the top left $2\times 2$ block of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Would the same apply to 
$$
A = \pmatrix{&3\\&&2\\1}
$$
then?

Comment: I added a matlab screenshot for both matrices. For second matrix, I am calling it B in my matlab code, $\mathbf{A^{'}}$ is top-right $2 \times 2$ block. So Yes. But I would say diagonal matrices are corner cases and might be misleading. Nevertheless, sliding window technique seems to be working for diagonal matrices.